# Bug in the Tag Wiki edit form

Tags: bug

There is a minor bug in the tag wiki edit form. In FireFox on Debian, the "excerpt" box is partially covered by the right hand sidebar.

[image]

It makes editing the excerpt a bit annoying as you can't see part of the content.

Comment: Hm, I can't confirm that for Firefox (20.0.1) on Windows 7...?

Comment: I see the issue on Debian and Slackware. I suspect it is Linux specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main content box has `width: 660px;` on that `textarea`

```
.wmd-input {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 660px;
}
```

The same width for the excerpt textarea should sort out the issue (tested with FireBug).

```
#excerpt {
  width:660px;
}
```